# Retrieve the group list using AWS cognito in C# .net from ListGroupsAsync function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When I am using the following function to get the group list then it show the error  message(in attachment):

```
RequestResult groupResult = new RequestResult();
ListGroupsResponse groupResponse = new ListGroupsResponse();
CognitoUser cognitoUser = (CognitoUser)result.Data;
ListGroupsRequest groupRequest = new ListGroupsRequest()
{
  NextToken = cognitoUser.SessionTokens.RefreshToken,
  UserPoolId = POOL_ID
};
try
{
  groupResponse = provider.ListGroups(groupRequest);
  groupResponse = await provider.ListGroupsAsync(groupRequest);
  groupResult.Data = groupResponse;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
return groupResult;
```

Error:

[image]